# Remove Bold/Italic/Underline in toolbar selection in WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview

Is it possible to remove the Bold/Italic/Underline selection when highlighting and selecting a text in `WKWebView`?

1. Select a word, then press "Select"

[image: Text selection menu with options]

2. The following dialog will present.  Notice the "Bold/Italic/Underline" section. How do I remove this?

[image: Text selection menu with "Bold/Italic/Underline" section]

Comment: I was commenting on your other post that it might be faster to chop your string into tokens and populate a `Set` or `Dictionary` where checking for inclusion would be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should subclass `WKWebView` and override `canPerformAction(_:withSender:)` in your subclass.

The selector that displays the bold/italic/underline menu item is called `_showTextStyleOptions:` and it's an Objective-C method. The double parentheses prevent the compiler from showing a warning that says the method is not accessible.

```
import WebKit

class CustomWebView: WKWebView {
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return action != Selector(("_showTextStyleOptions:"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer.  Only thing you left out was importing WebKit

Comment: @JoshO'Connor Thanks, I added the import statement.